# Is this function convex in $(W, v)$?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis

Define such a function on $(W,v)$, where $W \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a symmetric matrix. And $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector. Define $$f(W,v)=\| W -c \cdot vv^T \|_2.$$
Where $c\geq 0$ is a known scaler. I wanna known if $f$ is convex in $(W,v)$? It is trivial to see that when $c=0$, it is indeed convex because any norm function is convex. And, fix $v$, such a function is also convex in $W$ alone, since it is convex composed with affine inside. However, in general I cannot decide. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is my question clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were convex for all $n$, it better be convex for $n=1$. In this case

$$f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, \quad f(W,v) = |W - cv^2|$$
is something that is easy to understand and/or [plot](https://www.math3d.org/9bapKXemj). Unfortunately, this shows it isn't convex ($c=1$ for concreteness):
[image]

This 1D case embeds into the $n>1$ case since we can always consider the restriction of $f$ to the matrices $W$ which only have e.g. the top-left corner non-zero, and $v$ which have only its first coordinate non-zero. This set is convex and if $f$ were convex, its restriction to the convex set should be convex. So it's also false for all $n$.